# Custom section style using titlesec

Tags: luatex, titlesec, section-titles

Is there a way to modify the section label to anywhere else? For example, in the image below I would like the title to be right where it says "title here"
[image]

This is the titleformat:

```
    \titleformat{\section}
       [display]
       {\filcenter}
       { }{0em} 
       {\mbox{}\xrfill[0.4ex]{4pt}[rulecolor] {Title here} \mbox{}\xrfill[0.4ex]{4pt}[rulecolor]}
       []

    \begin{document}
    
       \section{Introduction}
       \lipsum[2]
    
    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last item in the last argument to `\titleformat` can be a macro expecting a further argument.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{xhfill}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\definecolor{rulecolor}{RGB}{228,228,239}

\titleformat{\section}[display]
  {\filcenter}
  {}
  {0em} 
  {\makesectiontitlenumbered{\thesection}}

\titleformat{name=\section,numberless}[display]
  {\filcenter}
  {}
  {0em} 
  {\makesectiontitlenonumber}

\newcommand{\makesectiontitlenumbered}[2]{%
  \mbox{}\xrfill[0.4ex]{4pt}[rulecolor]\ #1. #2\ \xrfill[0.4ex]{4pt}[rulecolor]%
}
\newcommand{\makesectiontitlenonumber}[1]{%
  \mbox{}\xrfill[0.4ex]{4pt}[rulecolor]\ #1\ \xrfill[0.4ex]{4pt}[rulecolor]%
}

\begin{document}

\section*{Introduction}

\lipsum[2]
    
\section{Preliminaries}

\lipsum[2]
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you don't want to number sections:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{xhfill}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\definecolor{rulecolor}{RGB}{228,228,239}

\titleformat{\section}[display]
  {\filcenter}
  {}
  {0em}
  {\makesectiontitle}

\newcommand{\makesectiontitle}[1]{%
  \mbox{}\xrfill[0.4ex]{4pt}[rulecolor]\ #1\ \xrfill[0.4ex]{4pt}[rulecolor]%
}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

\lipsum[2]

\section{Preliminaries}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the section title with `#1` in the `<before-code>` argument of `\titleformat` when using `titlesec`'s `explicit` option.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{xhfill}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\titleformat{\section}
   [display]
   {\filcenter}
   { }{0em} 
   {\mbox{}\xrfill[0.4ex]{4pt}[blue]\>#1\>\mbox{}\xrfill[0.4ex]{4pt}[blue]}
   []

\begin{document}

   \section{Introduction}
   \lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Both answers are really good! Thanks for your help!